Multiple Mongo validation types on single field?
Can a field validation in MongoDB collection contain string and null both as validation types.
{
  "$jsonSchema": {
    "bsonType": "object",
    "title": "Validations",
    "properties": {
      "t1": {
        "bsonType": "string",
        "description": "label field is required with min. 1 character in length"
      }
    }
  }
}

Can we specify field t1 be either a null or string type?

{ "bsonType": [ "null", "string" ] }

Just use { "bsonType": [ "null", "string" ] } like the official doc did.
{
  $jsonSchema: {
    properties: {
      t1: {
        bsonType: [
          'null',
          'string'
        ]
      }
    },
    description: 'label field is required with min. 1 character in length'
  }
}


I think just add 'null' into bsonType. We also could combine with another validation (example with minLength). It will be validated if the value is not null
{
  "$jsonSchema": {
    "bsonType": "object",
    "title": "Validations",
    "properties": {
      "t1": {
        "bsonType": ["string", "null"],
        "description": "t1 field can be a string with at least [number] character or null",
        "minLength": [number]
      }
    },
  }
}

